# Access Class Method with Php Closure properway

Tags: php, closures

```
Class Layout 
{
         
     public function menu()
     {
       Foo::create('topMenu',function($menu){
           $menu->logo($logolink);
           $menu->color('blue');
       });

     }


}


Class Foo 
{
    public static function create(string $menu, Closure $callback)
    {
      
    }
}


Class Menu
{

  public function logo(string $logo){}

  public function color(string $color){}

}
```

How to Access member method of Menu Class Inside Foo::create method with annonymus function?
$menu as Object of Menu Class..
Simple and Effective way in Core Php.

**Edited:**
I already try with

```
 public static function create(string $menu, Closure $callback)
    {
       return $callback(new Menu);
       // or return reflection of closure 
       // $callback->call(new Builder,$menu);
       // and then return..
    }
```

But If not returning object from Foo::create  it's not working
Currently working

```
Foo::create('topMenu',function($menu){
           $menu->logo($logolink);
           $menu->color('blue');
           return $menu;
       });
```

But need to be..Only without return $menu

```
       Foo::create('topMenu',function($menu){
           $menu->logo($logolink);
           $menu->color('blue');
       });
```

OR do like...

```
Foo::create('topMenu',function(Menu $menu){
           $menu->logo($logolink);
           $menu->color('blue');
       });
```

While I use function (Menu $menu){} My IDE working as expected but if use function($menu){} my IDE failed to showup $methods from $menu inside Foo::crete();

I think the IDE problem only for my side, is it same from your side?
phpstrom 2021.2.2

Comment: Ahh, it's solve, some plugins cause this ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
class Layout 
{
     public function menu()
     {
        // Here we print output for example:
        var_dump(Foo::create('topMenu', function($menu) {
           $menu->logo('link');
           $menu->color('blue');
           return $menu;
        }));
     }
}

class Foo 
{
    public static function create(string $menu, Closure $callback)
    {
        // Here we create new object of Menu class:
        return $callback(new Menu);
    }
}

class Menu
{

    public function logo(string $logo) {
        $this->logo = $logo;
    }

    public function color(string $color) {
        $this->color =  $color;
    }

}

// Run:
$layout = new Layout;
$layout->menu();
```

Here you can see example: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/1c866c17c607433bd91800facc1a948841cdf6eb

Comment: I did it already, but my phpstrom not auto display methods name, like it showing us for other instance. any idea why its not ide friendly.. $menu->color(); anyway your answer is correct, I accept you answer.

Comment: Hi @AloneCoder you didnt seem to accept the answer yet. You need to click the check mark in order to accept an answer